# How can I show in my tkinter GUI different frames depending on who logs in?

Tags: tkinter, logging, multiple-users

I am creating a tkinter app that uses a controller to switch between frames. In this app, I have added a login functionality. The next step is that different users with different rights can see a different GUI when starting the app, but I don't know yet how to do this.

I have though that a good solution would be to create a dictionary for the controller to loop trough. Initially, this dictionary would have the name of the 'basic' frames to start the app. Afterwards, when an user logs in, more frames related to this user's rights are added to this dictionary. When added the extra frames, I print the dictionary and these are shown. However, the app does not seem to know about them.

I have also tried with creating in the controller a dictionary for each user and equalling the initial dictionary to the logged in user's dictionary when logging in. I have tried too with lists, and tuples with the same result.

I don't really know what else to do. I don't think that to add long and multiple if statements fo all the frames that have widgets that depend on the logged in user's rights, it's a good solution. I am afraid, that the code would get really long and messy. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

I have, of course, tried to find information in this regard. However, I find but many links over logging in with Django and other stuff, not really related to what I am trying to find out.

Here is my code with the dictionary:

```
from tkinter import *


class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("1900x1080+0+0")

        container = Frame(self, background='white')
        container.pack(side='top', fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.user_type = {"User1": 'Admin', "User2": 'PM', "User3": 'Eng'}
        self.frames_list = {'a': Start, 'b': LoginWindow, 'c': FrameRed}
        self.frames = {}
        for F in self.frames_list.values():
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller1=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("Start")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        return frame


class Start(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller1):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(background='#004445')
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.controller1 = controller1

        self.start_button = Button(self, text='Start', bg='#F8B400', font=('Calibri', 22, 'bold'),
                                   width=10, command=lambda: controller1.show_frame('LoginWindow'))
        self.start_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='s', pady=20)


class LoginWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller1):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(background='#004445')
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=8)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=0)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=0)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=0)
        self.rowconfigure(4, weight=0)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.controller1 = controller1

        self.keys_list = []
        self.values_list = []

        self.log_frame = Frame(self, background='white')
        self.log_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, ipady=10)

        self.username_label = Label(self.log_frame, text="Username:  ", bg="white")
        self.username_label.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
        self.username_entry = Entry(self.log_frame)
        self.username_entry.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.button_login = Button(self.log_frame, text='Log in', width=10, height=1, bg='#F8B400',
                                   command=self.login_verification)
        self.button_login.grid(row=6, column=0)

        for x in self.controller1.user_type.keys():
            self.keys_list.append(x)

        for x in self.controller1.user_type.values():
            self.values_list.append(x)

    def login_verification(self):
        self.typed1 = self.username_entry.get()

        if self.keys_list[0] == self.typed1:
            if self.values_list[0] == 'Admin':
                self.controller1.frames_list['d'] = FrameGreen
                self.controller1.frames_list['e'] = FrameBlue
                print(self.controller1.frames_list)
                self.call_frame_red()
            else:
                pass
        elif self.keys_list[1] == self.typed1:
            if self.values_list[1] == 'PM':
                self.controller1.frames_list['d'] = FrameYellow
                self.controller1.frames_list['e'] = FrameBlue
                self.call_frame_red()
        elif self.keys_list[2] == self.typed1:
            if self.values_list[2] == 'Eng':
                self.controller1.frames_list['d'] = FrameGreen
                self.controller1.frames_list['e'] = FrameYellow
                self.call_frame_red()
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

    def call_frame_red(self):
        self.controller1.show_frame("FrameRed")

    def incorrect_user(self):
        Label(self.log_frame, text="User Not Found", bg="white").grid()


class FrameRed(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller1):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(bg='red')
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.green = Button(self, text='Frame Green', width=20, height=2, relief=FLAT, font=('Calibri', 14, 'bold'),
                            bg='#004445', command=lambda: controller1.show_frame('FrameGreen'))
        self.green.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20)


class FrameGreen(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller1):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(bg='green')
        self.controller1 = controller1
        self.blue = Button(self, text='Frame Blue', width=20, height=2, relief=FLAT, bg='#004445',
                           font=('Calibri', 14, 'bold'), command=lambda: controller1.show_frame('FrameBlue'))
        self.blue.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20)


class FrameBlue(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller1):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(bg='blue')
        self.controller1 = controller1
        self.yellow = Button(self, text='Yellow', command=lambda: controller1.show_frame("FrameYellow"))
        self.yellow.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


class FrameYellow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller1):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(bg='Yellow')
        self.controller1 = controller1
        self.red = Button(self, text='Red', bg='white', command=lambda: controller1.show_frame("FrameRed"))
        self.red.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I entered my name and not happened.

Comment: I finally created a file per user and pasted into each file the frames that I needed for each user. When logging in and interacting with the database, I call the frame of the corresponding file depending on who is logging in. Not sure if it is the best solution, but the best I came up with. For this, I had to import every file in the main one and add all the frames in the frames list of the Root's controller.